# What is a Ladder Switched Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I have recently read several papers with LSC on it (I'm taking care of my Mom 24/7, so I can't find them right now). Are Dickson and Cockroft-Walton considered Ladder, or am I off? Thanks.

Comment: I would call them ladders, yes.

Comment: They're ladders, but not switched, have a look at [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Switched-Capacitor-Ladder-dc-dc-Converter_fig3_291522689) for instance